# Reading RequestParameters in Freemarker template with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, httprequest, freemarker

I've searched all the web looking for an answer but could not fidn it. I hope someone was dealing with same issue.

I am developing application based on Spring MVC (3.1) and Freemarker (2.3.16). My Freemarker config looks like this:

```
 <!--  FreeMarker parsing -->
 <bean id="freemarkerConfig"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath"  value="/WEB-INF" />

     <property name="freemarkerSettings"> 
        <props>
             <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
             <prop key="output_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
     </property>

 </bean>


 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
      <property name="cache" value="true" />
      <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />

      <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"></property>

      <!-- if you want to use the Spring FreeMarker macros, set this property to true -->
      <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />

      <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"></property>

      <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
          <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />

 </bean>
```

It's pretty simple. I have no problem with rendering layout/views. The problem is with Spring Controller and writing Request Parameters into view. My simplest possible controller action is like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/simplest/action","/simplest"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
 @Transactional
 public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/simplest/action");        
     mv.addObject("myCustomIdFromView",  "66666" );
     return mv;
  }
```

View is rendered successfully. In this view I use such construction:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myCustomIdFromView" id="myCustomIdFromView" value="${myCustomIdFromView}" />
```

But with such construction Freemarker shows no value. If I change my input to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myCustomIdFromView" id="myCustomIdFromView" value="${myCustomIdFromView!'default'}" />
```

Then 'default' is rendered correctly. So I switched to RequestParameters. And another strange thing. With constructions:

```
{$RequestParameters.myCustomIdFromView}
{$RequestParameters['myCustomIdFromView']}
```

I receive empty values of Freemarker 'undefined'.

I've finally came to such solution.

```
<#assign myCustomIdFromView = '' />
<#list RequestParameters?keys as key>
 <#if key == 'myCustomIdFromView'>
    <#assign myCustomIdFromView = RequestParameters[key] />
    ${myCustomIdFromView}
 </#if>
</#list>
```

And IT'S WORKING! Can anyone tell me why I have problems with such simple thing like passing argument to ModelAndView and rendering it in a template? The values are (as You can see) in Model/Request Parameters but it's Freemarker that causes the problem? Any help appreciated.

Cheers, 
Chlebik

Comment: `${myCustomIdFromView!'default'}` prints `default` yet `${myCustomIdFromView}` doesn't throw an exception? That's so wrong... I hope Spring MVC doesn't configure FreeMarker like that. Also, `RequestParameters`, I believe, refers to the HTTP request query-string and form parameters, not to the request-object attributes (those are `Request.theAttributeName`, I believe). What does "I receive empty values of Freemarker 'undefined'." mean anyway?

Comment: I've written it not very clearly - I receive standard message: 'freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression myCustomIdFromView is undefined'

Comment: The last example still doesn't make sense. Does it print `6666`? That would be weird (unless you do have a query parameter or form field called `myCustomIdFromView`). Even then, the example could be simplified to `${RequestParameters.myCustomIdFromView!''}`.

Comment: BTW, what does `<#list .data_model?keys as k>${k},</#list>` print?

Comment: @ddekany - it prints 6666. I know it's weird - that's why I am looking for help. Given expression prints:  flash,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.cont,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.FLASH_MAP_MANAGER,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_SOURCE,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_RESOLVER,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.CONTEXT,

Comment: RequestParameters,org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService,springMacroRequestContext,actionName,org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.pathWithinHandlerMapping,Request,JspTaglibs,myCustomIdFromView,rc,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP,controllerName,Session,Application,org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.uriTemplateVariables,org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern,cont,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER

Comment: As You can see there's my variable on the list.

Comment: Well, I'm not at home with Spring, so why `${RequestParameters.myCustomIdFromView}` works at all (does it?), I don't know, maybe it has a fall-back to the model. Whatever. What I know is that if `.data_model` does contain `myCustomIdFromView`, then the only way `${myCustomIdFromView}` will fail is if its value is `null` (check with `${.data_model.myCustomIdFromView!'null'}`), or if somewhere something assigns `null` to *another* `myCustomIdFromView` variable that lives in the current FreeMarker-namespace or is a FreeMarker local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. I am using Spring MVC. Therefore there's default rule that says, that all `-servlet.xml` config files would be loaded by default.

In my `frontcontroller-servlet.xml` I had **import** statement, which included base `applicationContext.xml`. In this file I have another 3 imports (to support defragmentation of config files - with config for DB, controllers, etc).

But what wa also provided in **web.xml** was:

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext*</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And the result of these two things combined was double-creation of standard Spring beans. It came out when I started to integrate with Spring Security - suddenly my application was not able to be deployed - and exceptions were pointing out to double beans existing (`@Autowire` annotation went crazy).

So I assume that deep inside `Freemarker` classes for Spring (or in Spring itself) something happened and two models existed (with request params). Right now - when I use code from my question everything is rendering right.